# Does Elastic Search support aggregation query among multiple indices? Is it good practise?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack, amazon-emr, aws-elasticsearch

I have a use case with time-based (log like) data. If I go with rolling indices and create separate index for each day then I my queries will be spanning across multiple indices.

Is this a good practise?

I wanted to avoid going with monolith indices since the frequency of deletion is same as frequency of ingestion (log like) and I wanted to avoid bulk updates.

Is there any other alternative approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely a good practice. [Time-based indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/time-based.html) exist exactly for that purpose, i.e. to prevent having to cope with big monolithic indices. You can use [index lifecycle management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) in order to automatically set up rolling time-based indices.

The only requirement is that the aggregation query must run on a set of indices having the same mapping for the fields you're using in your query.

You can run your query either on a [list of indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) (`index1,index2,.../_search`) or [create an alias](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-add-alias.html) that spans all the desired time-based indices and then run your query on that alias (`alias_spanning_all_indices/_search`)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Can you please add link to the documentation of the same so that I can gain more insights.

Also how much heavier is it from computation perspective compared to the same operation in one index

Comment: Hey! I was diving deep on how ES internally aggregates results for a query in 1 index vs a query spanning multiple indices (from computation perspective)

Comment: You should take it for granted, that's an actual feature of ES, not a hack, so no worries there